# The word пахтярь

Tags: лексикон

Does anybody know what the word пахтярь means? It appears to refer to a profession.

I'm guessing it means "ploughman" but I can't find it in any dictionaries.

Answers in Russian are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В литературном русском языке слова "*пахтярь*" нет, но, в принципе, оно может быть диалектным производным от глагола "*пахтать*" (*to churn*), т.е. "*пахтярь*" = "*тот, кто пахтает*".

Также это может быть либо искажённым "*пахарь*" (ploughman), либо украинским "[*пахтяр*](http://explain_words_uk.academic.ru/4686/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%80)" - некий тип арендатора в сельском молочном хозяйстве (опять же, явно родственно глаголу "*пахтать*" - "*to churn*").

Comment: Google finds only one reference to spelling "пахтярь." It is a novel in Ukrainian by Ivan Franko ["Foundations of Society"](http://zbruc.eu/node/29717)  Hence the version of modified "пахтяр" (some kind of a renter он а milk farm) seems to be the likeliest.

Comment: Thank you. It's most likely a Russification of the Ukrainian word. A reference to the Ukrainian word was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

`ploughman` would be `пахарь` as any dictionary says. I've never heard `пахтярь` in Russian; perhaps it exists in some other Slavic language.

Answer (score 1):

**Пахтяр** (sic) is apparently Ukrainian for someone who rents farmland or cattle. Judging by the search results I get, it's probably obsolete.
http://explain_words_uk.academic.ru/4686/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%80